# Compare two values from two XML files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm parsing two xml files with identical structure, but with different data. After getting array of numbers, I need to compare each number from "file_1" to a similar similar from "file_2" and get alert, if it's greater or equal than number in "file_2". The problem is, that my code compares arrays in whole, and if there is at lest one number in "file_2" greater, than in "file_1", I don't get alert.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import urllib.request


def main():
    # using parse() for downloading and parsing XML file
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('URL_to_file_1', 'file_1.xml')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('URL_to_file_2', 'file_2.xml')
    doc_1 = xml.dom.minidom.parse("file_1")
    doc_2 = xml.dom.minidom.parse("file_2")

    availableMethods = ['method1', 'method2']
    availableData = ['data1', 'data2']
    # getting list of XML tags from document
    items_1 = doc_1.getElementsByTagName("item")
    items_2 = doc_2.getElementsByTagName("item")

    for item in items_1:
        method_1 = item.getElementsByTagName("from")[0]
        to_1 = item.getElementsByTagName("to")[0]
        out_1 = item.getElementsByTagName("out")[0]
        if method_1.firstChild.data in availableMethods and to_1.firstChild.data in availableData:
            numbers_1 = float(out_1.firstChild.data)
            print("method_1:%s, to_1:%s, out_1:%s" % (method_1.firstChild.data, to_1.firstChild.data, out_1.firstChild.data))

    for item in items_2:
        method_2 = item.getElementsByTagName("from")[0]
        to_2 = item.getElementsByTagName("to")[0]
        out_2 = item.getElementsByTagName("out")[0]
        if method_2.firstChild.data in availableMethods and to_2.firstChild.data in availableData:
            numbers_2 = float(out_2.firstChild.data)
            print("method_2:%s, to_2:%s, out_2:%s" % (method_2.firstChild.data, to_2.firstChild.data, out_2.firstChild.data))

    if numbers_2 <= numbers_2:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("BAD")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

file_1.xml

```
<rates>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00006084091504736</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00007190617745180</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000 EUR</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00225030292539380</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00266214200040956</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 </rates>
```

file_2.xml

```
<rates>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00076084091504736</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00077190617745180</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.07225030292539380</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.07266214200040956</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 </rates>
```

I need to compare each "out" value from method+data pair in "file_1", to similar "out" value in "file_2" and get alert if there is an "out" in "file_1" greater or equal than "out" in "file_2".

Comment: share the xml files and explain what is the expected output

Comment: added xml files and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below. the idea is to extract the 'key' data and the 'value' data from the 2 xml docs. Loop over both and compare.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml1 = '''<rates>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00006084091504736</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00007190617745180</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000 EUR</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00225030292539380</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00266214200040956</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 </rates>'''

xml2 = '''<rates>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00076084091504736</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data1</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.00077190617745180</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method1</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.07225030292539380</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>105</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 <item>
    <from>method2</from>
    <to>data2</to>
    <in>1</in>
    <tofee>0.0006</tofee>
    <out>0.0000007266214200040956</out>
    <amount>39.508888709782</amount>
    <minamount>90</minamount>
    <maxamount>10000</maxamount>
 </item>
 </rates>'''

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
root2 = ET.fromstring(xml2)
items1 = root1.findall('.//item')
items2 = root2.findall('.//item')
# I need to compare each "out" value from method+data pair in "file_1", to similar "out" value in "file_2" and get alert
# if there is an "out" in "file_1" greater or equal than "out" in "file_2".
data1 = {(e.find('from').text, e.find('to').text): float(e.find('out').text) for e in items1}
data2 = {(e.find('from').text, e.find('to').text): float(e.find('out').text) for e in items2}
for k, v in data1.items():
    print(f'key: {k} -> xml1 out: {v} | xml2 out: {data2[k]}')
    if v >= data2[k]:
        print(f'Alert: {v} >= {data2[k]}')
```

output

```
key: ('method1', 'data1') -> xml1 out: 6.084091504736e-05 | xml2 out: 0.00076084091504736
key: ('method2', 'data1') -> xml1 out: 7.19061774518e-05 | xml2 out: 0.0007719061774518
key: ('method1', 'data2') -> xml1 out: 0.0022503029253938 | xml2 out: 0.0722503029253938
key: ('method2', 'data2') -> xml1 out: 0.00266214200040956 | xml2 out: 7.266214200040956e-07
Alert: 0.00266214200040956 >= 7.266214200040956e-07
```